# What is changing the network interfaces?

Tags: 12.04, networking, dhcp, remastersys, relinux

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 to virtual machine. I have edited `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Then I created a livecd.iso using relinux. Network interfaces is changing after boot from DVD (livecd.iso).

`/etc/network/interfaces` after boot from DVD:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
```

But It is changing different if I boot livecd.iso via NFS.

`/etc/network/interfaces` after boot via NFS(Network File System):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
```

I'm really confused. What is changing the network interfaces? How can I prevent the changes?

Note: After some research, someone pointed me `` `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules `` file. It was empty. I removed it and created livecd.iso again but same things happened.